# Is it possible to draw a line chart in MailApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use Google Apps scripts in Google Ads for alerting purposes.

Is there a way to draw a line chart from Google Ads data and send it as
HTML via MailApp?

Comment: You can render it in a dialog or webapp and get the Image using Google Visualization API chart.getImageURI(); method and save the dataURI on google drive and then send it in an email.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I saved the image from a webapp chart:

js:

```
var chart=new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('GasTest'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'ready',function(){
        gdatObj['imagURI']=chart.getImageURI();
        gdatObj.ready=true;
        saveGasTestChartImage();

function saveGasTestChartImage(){
      //working on this
      google.script.run.saveGasTestChartImage(gdatObj);      
    }
```

gs:

```
function saveGasTestChartImage(gdatObj){
  var selObj=getSelectedProject();
  var fileName=Utilities.formatString('GTCImg%s',selObj.pid);
  var imagesFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(getGlobal('ImagesDirectoryId'));
  var dupImages=imagesFolder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  while(dupImages.hasNext()){
    dupImages.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
  imagesFolder.createFile(fileName,gdatObj.imagURI,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```